# Pydantic: Export fields of the same type with different encodings

Tags: python, pydantic

Suppose I have a model with various `timedelta` fields, but I want them each expressed in a different format when exported to JSON. I know I can specify the JSON encoder for `timedelta`, but that applies to all fields of that type. Is there a way to specify the JSON encoder for a given field? or is there another way to accomplish this?

Here's a bit of code as an example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.json import timedelta_isoformat


class Example(BaseModel):
    delta_iso: timedelta # export using timedelta_isoformat
    delta_seconds_int: timedelta # export as int in seconds
    delta_seconds_float: timedelta # export as float in seconds
    delta_milliseconds_int: timedelta # export as int in milliseconds

    class Config:
        # This won't work because it applies to all fields above
        json_encoders = {
            timedelta: timedelta_isoformat,
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide custom [`json_dumps`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#custom-json-deserialisation) function. Like so:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.json import timedelta_isoformat


def custom_dumps(v, *, default):
    for key, value in v.items():
        if key == "delta_iso":
            v[key] = timedelta_isoformat(value)
        elif key == "delta_seconds_int":
            v[key] = int(value.total_seconds())
        elif key == "delta_seconds_float":
            v[key] = value.total_seconds()
        elif key == "delta_milliseconds_int":
            v[key] = value.total_seconds() * 1000
    return json.dumps(v, default=default)


class Example(BaseModel):
    delta_iso: timedelta # export using timedelta_isoformat
    delta_seconds_int: timedelta # export as int in seconds
    delta_seconds_float: timedelta # export as float in seconds
    delta_milliseconds_int: timedelta # export as int in milliseconds

    class Config:
        json_dumps = custom_dumps

diff = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=5000)
print(Example(delta_iso=diff, delta_seconds_int=diff, delta_seconds_float=diff, delta_milliseconds_int=diff).json())
```

```
{"delta_iso": "P0DT0H0M5.000000S", "delta_seconds_int": 5, "delta_seconds_float": 5.0, "delta_milliseconds_int": 5000.0}
```

Comment: amazing! I did see the ability to set `json_dumps` but it didn't occurr to me to use it to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, `model_dump(mode="...")` (which currently includes `json` and `python` modes) is eventually making its way into Pydantic, as discussed by the library's author in Pydantic's [issue #1409](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1409#issuecomment-1423995424):

> This is actually already implemented in pydantic-core and works on main now.
>
> Example:
>
> ```py
> from datetime import datetime
> from pydantic import BaseModel
>
>
> class MyModel(BaseModel):
>     things: set[str]
>     when: datetime
>
>
> m = MyModel(things={'a', 'b'}, when=datetime.now())
> print(m.model_dump(mode='json'))
> """
> {
>     'things': ['b', 'a'],
>     'when': '2023-02-09T10:54:50.11279',
> }
> """
> ```

As of today (March 9, 2023) it has not been packaged as a release, but it's in the `main` branch as of [`f4e8f71ab23a`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/commit/f4e8f71ab23a427662f8ac67ba04e453ece56cf3#diff-8708af8d26c26644976866f974e0b810b0940ede43ff487e457057d5a1f07999R228) and you can always try it out in the meantime by pinning your `pydantic` package to the appropriate `main` revision on GitHub.